# What's the best way to launch a view after device is unlocked?

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a view that the user must dismiss each time they unlock their phone (it's intended to be annoying). It should be able to take a small amount of keyboard input, save it, then return to the previously open activity. I tried having a BroadcastReceiver listen for ACTION_USER_PRESENT and launch my own activity, but then I found out we can [no longer listen for implicit intents](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts), or have [background services launch activities](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services).

I'm not an Android developer (just trying to build something for my phone), but I did some looking, and I see a few options:

1. Display a full-screen intent. I think something like scheduling a job to raise a notification whenever the phone is locked, so that the notification appears first thing when they unlock the phone.
2. Use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and draw my view as an overlay whenever the phone is unlocked. My only concern with this is how apps like Twilight (which I believe draws an overlay to redden the screen) might interact with it. In those cases, I'd like my overlay to appear at the very bottom.

Are either of those options viable or recommended? Any other suggestions or approaches for how I could accomplish this would be greatly appreciated too. I'm just looking for some guidance on what direction I should pursue.